# Outlook Desktop Alert Dialog Box that stays more than 30 sec?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, alert

Is there a way (Prefs, plugin) to ask outlook to leave the Desktop Alert Dialog Box visible until I see it ?  I'm frequently away from computer and I want to have a visual clue that tells me that some emails have arrived during the time I was away.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/221), however it is not as pretty as the desktop alert dialog, which was made for you when you are at the workstation. The new item alert window must be manually closed.

30 seconds is the max of the desktop alert dialog, unless there is some reg hack I haven't looked into.